# Волька ибн Алеша

Tags: имена-собственные

Все мы в детстве читали сказку Лагина "Старик Хоттабыч" и помним, что главного героя звали Волька. Хоттабыч называл его Волька ибн Алеша. А вот мне всегда было интересно, какое полное имя у Вольки? В смысле, от какого имени это уменьшение?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Насколько помню, в книге прямо написано, что полное имя мальчика Костыльков Владимир Алексеевич.

Comment: А ибн Алеша - это Алексеевич.

Comment: >А ибн Алеша - это Алексеевич.  
  
Алешевич. Ибн - на фарси "сын"

Answer (score 2):

По книге - уже сказали. Правда, похоже, автор немножко пофантазировал.
А вообще ***Волька*** как уменьшительное употребительно для имен Вольдемар, Валерий, Валентин и других. Лично мне кажется основным Валерий. Конечно, выборка среди моих знакомых недостаточная, чтобы судить наверняка, но как минимум троих Валериев-Волек я знавал. А вот отальных - только по книгам.

Answer (score 1):

имя "Волька" было очень популярным в 30-40- х.Как раз в эти годы в СССР проживало много "интернациональнго элемента".Во время войны,такие имена как Адольф,Рудольф,Вольфганг и др.приобрели в звучании резко враждебную окраску.А такие адаптированные варианты,как Волька,Адька,Рудька...звучали нейтрально и даже по "свойски".

Answer (score 0):

Волька - старое немецкое имя ( Volker ) 
https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volker

Comment: Да, ещё: V - в немецком языке читается как Ф (Фолька).   А буква (Л -  L) если в конце слова или перед согласной произносится магко. 
ФоЛька - Волька

Comment: И вот Лагин в период не самых теплых отношений с Германией дает русскому пионеру, вероятному Валентину или Валерию Алексеевичу, старое немецкое имя - да еще с испорченной фонетикой. Задорнов, однако.

Comment: Да. *L в немецком **всегда** мягкий.* А не только "в конце и перед".